# Ember.Js title repetitiveness

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Hi guys I wanted to ask why does a word keep popping up in other pages on my ember website. To clarify I mean that I have a main homepage but then I go to a products page->return to my homepage and I have the title of the products page showing up. It is very annoying because I've been learning ember and how simple I can connect many static pages, I do not want go go back to simple html. Here is the code below. Thank you everyone.

Note: This is just the Mainpage.html. I am using php to include all these pages to my index so that might have something to do with it.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name='index'>
<div id="main-page-container">
<h1>Technological Business Marketplace</h1>
</div>
<div id="main-page-container">
<p>There are {{productsCount}} products</p>
<img {{bind-attr src='img/slidelogo.png'}} alt='Logo' />
<p>uploaded on {{time}}</p>
</div>

<div>
 <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="wrapper-filter">
        <ul id="filter">
            <li class="active">All</li>
            <li>Applications</li>
            <li>Websites</li>
            <li>Services</li>
            <li>Domains</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <ul id="portfolio">
        <li class="All Applications"><img id="1" src="img/loginback.jpg" alt=""/></li>
        <li class="All Websites"><img id="2" src="img/loginback.jpg" alt=""/></li>
        <li class="All Websites"><img id="3" src="img/loginback.jpg" alt=""/></li>
        <li class="All Services"><img id="4" src="img/loginback.jpg" alt=""/></li>
        <li class="All Services"><img id="5" src="img/loginback.jpg" alt=""/></li>
        <li class="All Domains"><img id="6" src="img/loginback.jpg" alt=""/></li>
        <li class="All Domains"><img id="7" src="img/loginback.jpg" alt=""/></li>
        <li class="All Domains"><img id="8" src="img/loginback.jpg" alt=""/></li>
        <li class="All Services"><img id="9" src="img/loginback.jpg" alt=""/></li>
        <li class="All Websites"><img id="10" src="img/loginback.jpg" alt=""/></li>
        <li class="All Services"><img id="11" src="img/loginback.jpg" alt=""/></li>
        <li class="All Websites"><img id="12" src="img/loginback.jpg" alt=""/></li>
        <li class="All Domains"><img id="13" src="img/loginback.jpg" alt=""/></li>
        <li class="All Services"><img id="14" src="img/loginback.jpg" alt=""/></li>
        <li class="All Applications"><img id="15" src="img/loginback.jpg" alt=""/></li>
        <li class="All Applications"><img id="16" src="img/loginback.jpg" alt=""/></li>
        <li class="All Domains"><img id="17" src="img/loginback.jpg" alt=""/></li>
        <li class="All Services"><img id="18" src="img/loginback.jpg" alt=""/></li>
        <li class="All Applications"><img id="19" src="img/loginback.jpg" alt=""/></li>
        <li class="All Applications"><img id="20" src="img/loginback.jpg" alt=""/></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
</script>
<script src="js/filter.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you u reproduce ur issue in jsbin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got bad html, a missing closing div or something of the sort.